# Give offset to text

Tags: html, css

I'm using `Jquery` `DataTable` and because of that sorting icon my th header is not centered with the td data.

How do I give an offset to the text?

I tried `right: -9px` but it moves the whole th and leaves a blank gap between them.

> https://prnt.sc/ihq2y5

Comment: add also `position: relative;` then you can use `right: -9px;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a negative text-indent on the table header, e.g.

```
th {
  text-indent: -9px
}
```

See the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-indent)